# Is there a way to update a windows form in a loop?

Tags: c#, winforms

My goal is to make a desktop pet. I've already programmed a lot of logic that executes in a while loop and updates every iteration. To display the creature I'm looking to use windows forms, but that has brought up a dilemma.

I want to be able to execute the logic, and then update the window in the same loop (process events and redraw), without having to deal with `Application.Run()` or multi threading. As an example, and as someone who's come from python, using tkinter it's possible to call the `update()` method on a window in a loop, which is essentially the same as calling `mainloop()` once, except it doesn't block the program.

Do forms offer any similar functionality?

Comment: It does provide the functionality but it is not the correct way to solve the problem in winforms. You should look in to replaceing your loops with timers that run the body of the loop function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Scott Chamberlain mentioned, you should use a timer to run your 'loop'. Winforms is event based so adding an infinite loop will freeze the program since events are blocked.

This code illustrates how to use a timer. I added a picture box to the form and it moves across the screen as the timer fires.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Timer tmr = new Timer();
        tmr.Interval = 50;   // milliseconds
        tmr.Tick += Tmr_Tick;  // set handler
        tmr.Start();
    }

    private void Tmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)  //run this logic each timer tick
    {
        pictureBox1.Left += 1;  // move image across screen, picture box is control so no repaint needed
    }
}
```